How is this sentence exactly divided? Usage of と

（今までこれは恋愛感情だと、愛情からだと、嫉妬からだと彼に伝えずに来てしまっている……）
それが何を意味するか
感情が自分で正しく認識できるようになった今ならわかる

The character concludes they are in love with their friend, and give out this reasoning.
However, I'm a bit stumbled on the first part of the sentence here.
My reading would be that the first と is an if "恋愛感情だと" while the second is a quotation?
"If until now it was romantic love, I ended up going to him without telling him it's because of jealousy and affection"?

All three と are quotative-と that modify 伝えず. Parse the sentence like this:

今まで、「 これは  恋愛感情だ」と、
        「(これは) 愛情からだ」と、
        「(これは) 嫉妬からだ」と   彼に伝えずに来てしまっている


Until now, I've ended up not telling him that this was a romantic feeling, that it was from love, that it was from jealousy...

Note that くる here does not refer to physical movement. It's used as a subsidiary verb indicating the continuation of a state up until now.
